# Find if List contains object with property

Tags: java

I have a 3 lists: `Sales, Customers, Items` holding objects of their own namesakes.

I have a method:

```
public boolean sellItem(int itemId, int customerId) {
        if (customers.contains(customerId) && items.contains(itemId)){
            for (Item i : items) {
                if(i.getItemId() == itemId && i.getStockNum()>0) {
                    sales.add(new Sale(LocalDateTime.now(), itemId, customerId, i.getCost()));
                    i.sell();
                }
                for (Customer c : customers) {
                    if (c.getCustomerId() == customerId) {
                        c.charge(i.getCost());
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

However I understand that I cannot find if a list contains something like their ID, but only if they contain a full object etc.

Is there anyway to make this work in a simple way that I'm missing?

Comment: Use an iterator and manually check each object for your condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to do something like `if (customers.contains(customerId) && items.contains(itemId))` when you are already checking if there's an object with that ID inside the 'for' loops? It looks like it would work just deleting that 'if' statement.

Comment: YOU ARE CORRECT! Turns out that I'm a massive burke! Thanks for the help Sergio. I will accept when it lets me.